# The IR/ H-NMR analysis of benzophenone?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, nmr-spectroscopy, ir-spectroscopy

I think I have figured out the IR spectrum for benzophenone. Would it be that the sharp peak in the middle (1700 cm^-1) is for the ketone and the little peaks pass 2900 cm^-1 rang are the sp2/sp3 carbons from the benzene rings?

[image]

Also, I have an H-NMR spectrum for the same compound and I know there are only three peaks because the compound is symmetrical. But I am confused on how to determine the J values for each hydrogen.

[image]

Can someone kindly assist?

Comment: If you print expanded portion with the resonance in Hz, you can easily calculate *J* values.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: Your peaks in the main spectrum is in $\pu{ppm}$. You have to print it again in $\pu{Hz}$ (there is a option to do so in printing software). Then expand it to be more clear. It is hard to read and isolate in compact mode.

Comment: Oh...I had to screenshot this photo because I was unable to save it correctly especially since it was given to me as a cropped photo. Because of this, I was wondering if I can figure the J values another way

Comment: Do you know the power of spectrometer? Such as whether it is $\pu{400 MHz}$ or higher or lower, but exact number?  If so, each $\Delta\delta$ in $\pu{ppm}$ can be multiply by that numerical value (*e.g.*, $400$) to get approximate $J$ in $\pu{Hz}$. This calculation is based on this: For instance, for a spectrum in $\pu{400 MHz}$, $\pu{1 ppm} = \pu{400 Hz}$.

Comment: I'll ask because that picture was all I was given.

Comment: Why do you want the J couplings? The assignment of all peaks is totally clear without, and the two triplets are higher order peaks anyway, so analysing the coupling is not trivial.

Comment: In the ir there is a CO, and many CC and CH vibrations and of these the CH might be expected to have the highest frequency.